# Считать матрицу из файла

Tags: c, файлы, матрицы

код на си
вроде,сколько смотрела по форумам, код правильный
грешу на ввод размерности с клавиатуры
выводит матрицу заполненную нулями
когда добавила

```
if(fp==NULL)
{
   puts("Open file error");
   return;
}
```

стало выводить "Open file error"

подскажите,пожалуйста, в чем проблема

```
printf("Введите количество строк матрицы А ");
scanf("%d", &m);
printf("Введите количество столбцов матрицы А ");
scanf("%d", &n);

float A[m][n];

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("matrixA.txt", "rt");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    puts("Open file error");
    return;
}

for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%f ", &A[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\nМатрица А \n");

for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%f\t", A[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: а файл точно есть? А права доступа к нему правило выставлены?

Comment: Ошибки надо выводить как-то так: `printf( "Can not open file \"%s\" : %s\n", filename, strerror(errno) );` **или** `perror( "Can not open file" );` Без этого - подземный стук, который и обсуждать смысла нет.

Comment: А лежит ли файл в каталоге программы?

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а что во втором параметре в `fp = fopen("matrixA.txt", "rt");` означает буква `t`? Разве там не могут быть только `a`, `a+`, `w`, `w+`, `r`, `r+`?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема у вас в том, что не открывается файл `matrixA.txt`. Скорее всего, его просто нет в **текущем каталоге**, из которого запускается ваша программа.

То, что раньше этого сообщения не было, не говорит о том, что все было хорошо - просто программа не жаловалась, что ей на самом деле плохо... :)

Comment: Не знаю. Все лежит в одной папке. Сначала все на рабочем столе было, а потом еще и в отдельную папку кинула, но ничего это не дало.

Comment: "*не знаю*" - это не разговор вообще. Либо приводите **точную диагностику** (пример - выше в комментарии), либо разговаривать и не о чем.